# ms access auto fill main form based on focus of subform

Tags: ms-access, forms, autocomplete, focus, subform

I have a data entry/editing form with two combo boxes (Name and Group).

- Each Group correlates to multiple names but each name is in only one group.
- At the bottom of this form is a subform which is a continuous form
  displaying a query of the associated table filtered based on an
  unbound combo from which you select the group.

Basically, you choose which group you want to see and it displays a list of all the Names in that Group.

I want to make this form able to **add** and **delete** Names from the table (which it does with buttons already), but I also want to be able to **select** a Name from the subform and have the main form focus on that entry and auto fill the two bound combos.

And then from there I would like to be able to **edit** and **save** that entry or just **delete** the entry.

Similarly, I would like to be able to add a new entry without worrying about writing over a current entry. Access might do this automatically; if this is the case:

Is it even possible to **edit** an entry without deleting and then replacing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also want to be able to select a
>   Name from the subform and have the
>   main form focus on that entry and auto
>   fill the two bound combos.

To do that, you can do a FindRecord on the main form's recordset, using the ID from the subform.  The form will move to the correct record.  From the subform's OnCurrent Event:

```
 Forms!MyMainForm.Recordset.FindFirst "MyID = " & desiredRecordID
```

or

```
 Forms!MyMainForm.Recordset.FindFirst "MyID = '" & desiredRecordID & "'"
```

> Similarly, I would like to be able to
>   add a new entry without worrying about
>   writing over a current entry.

To do that, execute the following code:

```
 DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "MyMainForm", acNewRec
```

Comment: ok i changed it up a little bit.  I now have an unbound combo that i want to choose MyID from and i want the main form to autofill based on that.  
I tried Forms!MyMainForm.Recordset.FindFirst "MyID = " & myCombo  
but it gives me an error saying that theres a missing operator.

Comment: Try putting single quotes around the myCombo value, (see edit above) and let's see what happens.

Comment: now im getting a data type mismatch error.  i checked to make sure, and the unbound combo and the bound combo are the same data type.

Comment: got it.  theres a typo in your edit.  the single quote at the end needs to be in double quotes like this  
Forms!MyMainForm.Recordset.FindFirst "MyID = '" & desiredRecordID & "'"  
works now though.  thank you a ton.